# ArgoUML - Learning

Tags: design, uml

So I just got a copy of ArgoUML.  I originally thought I'd be able to just play around with it to learn it, but it's turning out to be extremely difficult.  I searched online for tutorials and videos but came up with nothing useful.

The help file for ArgoUML is very incomplete as well.

Does anybody know of any online resources to help me learn ArgoUML (and UML in general, I guess)?

Thanks!

Comment: I think your last sentence confuses things. Can you be clear, are you looking for help on ArgoUML as a tool, or UML in general?

Comment: I have noticed that the learning curve for well documented pay license UML modeling software to be very high as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your focus should be on learning UML.  After you know UML any of the many UML tools available will be easy to learn with or without documentation.  (Personally I would recommend the free version of astah as I have found it to be much easier to use with much better functionality than ArgoUML).  Some of the key things to focus on would be:

- Use-Case Diagrams
- Class Diagrams
- Sequence Diagrams

Kennesaw State University has a nice little intro on UML. ([Here](http://atlas.kennesaw.edu/~dbraun/csis4650/A&D/UML_tutorial/index.htm)) After that I would recommend that you google aspects of UML that you're interested in.  Again don't google specific diagramming tools as there are many and the information will be spotty at best.  There is a lot of information out there about UML.  Keep in mind though that everyone utilizes UML differently so you'll need to be prepared when you join different teams for that to become an issue.

Comment: However, if your problem is with the tool, use the tool's forum at:http://www.argouml-users.net/forum/